# php visibility modifier confusing part

Tags: php, oop

I'm completely beginner in PHP OOP and try to learning PHP visibility modifier.
In private modifier, I can access private property and method from its own class.
But you can see my code that I can access an private property from a child class called **VisibilityModifierChild**. please check my code comment for better understands or you can run the code in an online PHP interpreter for more info.

```
class VisibilityModifier {
    public $pub_variable = "public property";
    protected $pro_variable = "protected property - <strong>getPro() method</strong>";
    private $pri_variable = "private property - <strong>getPri() method</strong>";

    //set getter for protected variable
    public function getPro() {
        return $this->pro_variable;
    }
    //set getter for private variable
    public function getPri() {
        return $this->pri_variable;
    }
}

class VisibilityModifierChild extends VisibilityModifier {
    public function setPubVariable($set) {
        $this->pub_variable = $set;
    }

    public function setProVariable($set) {
        $this->pro_variable = $set;
    }

    // cannot set the value but it does't give any warning and error -- sound cofusing
    public function setPriVariable($set) {
        $this->pri_variable = $set;
    }

    // set and get a private property from child class -- sound confusing
    public function getPrivateByChild ($set) {
        $this->pri_variable = $set;
        return $set;
    }

}


$visible = new VisibilityModifier();
$visible_child = new VisibilityModifierChild();


echo $visible->pub_variable . "<strong style=\"color:green\">-Looks Good</strong><br>";
$visible_child->setPubVariable("child access public property");
echo $visible_child->pub_variable . "<strong style=\"color:green\"> -Looks Good</strong><br>";

echo '<hr>';

// echo $visible->pro_variable . "<br>"; 
echo $visible_child->getPro() . "<strong style=\"color:green\"> -Looks Good</strong><br>";
$visible_child->setProVariable("child access protected property<strong style=\"color:green\"> -Looks Good</strong>");
echo $visible_child->getPro() . "<br>";

echo '<hr>';


// echo $visible->pri_variable . "<br>"; 
echo $visible->getPri() . "<strong style=\"color:green\"> -Looks Good</strong><br>";
$visible_child->setPriVariable("child access private property") . "<br>";
echo $visible_child->getPri() . "<strong style=\"color:red\"> -sound confusing</strong><br>";
echo $visible_child->getPrivateByChild("child can access private property<strong style=\"color:red\"> -sound confusing</strong>") . "<br>";
```

Comment: Put this `var_dump('<xmp>','child_$pri_variable', $this->pri_variable, 'parent_$pri_variable', parent::getPri(), '</xmp>');` in your setPriVariable() function as last statement and check the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dump the child instance, you will see that there are now two properties "pri_variable":

```
object(VisibilityModifierChild)#2 (4) {
  ["pub_variable"]=>
  string(15) "public property"
  ["pro_variable":protected]=>
  string(53) "protected property - <strong>getPro() method</strong>"
  ["pri_variable":"VisibilityModifier":private]=>
  string(51) "private property - <strong>getPri() method</strong>"
  ["pri_variable"]=>
  string(29) "child access private property"
}
```

The unchanged private property to which you have no access and the one you set dynamically when you invoked the setter.

Since the child class cannot see the private property, it will just create a new property with the same name in it's own instance scope (this). It may appear as if you are accessing the private property, but you are really creating a new property. The private property is unchanged.